# (Safari Only) Axios request does not send cookies to Node.js/Express REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, safari, localhost

### Problem

I am building a Vue.js web app and a Node.js/Express REST API.

When sending cookies after login, they are received, but not send back with the next request.

#### Backend

Node.js/Express REST API (running locally over HTTP (not HTTPS) on `http://localhost:3000`)

CORS is enabled using middleware with the following options:

```js
app.use(require('cors')({
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'http://localhost:8080'],
    methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE',
    credentials: true
}))
```

After a successful login (which required a successful OPTIONS/preflight request), the response looks as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Origin
Set-Cookie: session=XXX; Max-Age=604800; Path=/api/v0; Expires=Thu, 02 Apr 2020 15:36:42 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: token=XXX; Max-Age=1800; Path=/api/v0; Expires=Thu, 26 Mar 2020 16:06:42 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 15:36:42 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 203
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: W/"cb-dRDu0E2yjk3BHs7J/aXoYLLzsGM"
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Download-Options: noopen
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
```

So to reiterate: cookies are set including `Max-Age`, `Path`, `Expires`, `HttpOnly`, and `SameSite=Lax` parameters after a successful CORS OPTIONS preflight request.

#### Frontend

Vue.js web app using Axios (running locally over HTTP (not HTTPS) on `http://localhost:8080`)

Requests are sent using Axios with the `withCredentials: true` option. With Firefox, the token and session cookies are automatically included as a `Cookie: session=XXX; token=XXX` header, but on Safari they are not.

```js
import Axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

const API = Axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v0',
    timeout: 5000,
    withCredentials: true
})

...

async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<AuthenticationResponse> {
    return handleResponse(API.post('/auth/login', { email, password }))
}

...

async getUserById(id: string): Promise<UserResponse> {
    return handleResponse(API.get('/users/' + id))
}
```

How can I solve this? Is Safari safer in some way that it is not willing to send the cookies? What settings do I change on the frontend or backend?

Comment: Please show the exact client code that is sending the Ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it's ridiculous...

Navigate to the web app using `127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `localhost:8080` and everything works as intended.